# Require One Post per Category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I have created a website in wordpress... and my requirement is that I need one post per category on homepage..

Below is my Code in PHP:

```
$args = array('type' => 'post', 'orderby'  => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'number' => '10', 'taxonomy'  => 'category');
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 
   $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$category->cat_ID.'&order=DESC' );  
   while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();

     echo "Some div & links";

   endwhile; 
 }
```

The above code give me all post in all category... How to get the only 1 latest post per category..??

Wat should i change in above code..??? Please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved the issue.. please check the below code

```
$args = array('type' => 'post', 'orderby'  => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC',  'number' => '10', 'taxonomy'  => 'category');
$categories = get_categories($args);

foreach($categories as $category) { 
  $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$category->cat_ID.'&order=DESC' );  
  $catquery->the_post();

   echo "Some div & links";     
}
```

I just removed while loop...:)